# Python, Javascript: Fetch data inside .js file

Tags: javascript, python, flask

In Flask, we can pass a data from .py to .html using Jinja2. I wonder if it's possible to pass a data from .py to .js file. I can fetch the data if I include `<script>$('.user').mentionsInput...</script>` inside the .html file but I want to separate the .js file so that I can use it in another .html file.

`users.js`

```
$('.user_mention').mentionsInput({
  source: [
    {% for user in users %}
    {value: {{user.name}}, uid: {{user.id}}},
    {% endfor %}
  ],
  showAtCaret: True
});
```

Comment: Would it help if the .py put data in hidden fields eg. a div, in the html and then read those field contents in js? I've passed small amounts of data around that way.

Comment: @Paul Does it allow to render a template with  .js file  like `return render_template('users.js', users=users)` ?

Comment: I think I found the answer to my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315368/how-can-i-render-a-js-template-from-a-rendered-html-template