# In Javascript and Flask can I pass Jinja2 variable inside a script that is a module

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I would like to pass a Jinja2 variable into a .js file. Then call the file from my page. Is that possible.

example:

test.js file

```
alert('{{myFlaskVar}}')
```

page.html

```
<script src="/static/scripts/test.js"></script> //but pass the myFlaskVar
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315368/how-can-i-render-a-js-template-from-a-rendered-html-template/38315457

Comment: @PaxVobiscum Really cool. Thanks!