# form.validate_on_submit(): and {{ form.csrf_token }} not working in a view.html with two forms

Tags: validation, flask, wtforms, csrf-token

In http://127.0.0.1:5000/:

If defaults are "0", message in each  field: "This field is required".
There are the message "csrf_token CSRF Token" above "compute0" and "compute1".
Only compute0 works.

click on compute0 shows the resulted.
click on compute1 showns nothing.

form and form1 have 3 inputs.
compute0 and compute1 call (math.sin(r))* t + u.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import TextField, BooleanField, PasswordField, TextAreaField, validators
from compute import compute
from model import InputForm, InputForm1
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Thisisasecret'
    
    @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
    
    def index():
        form = InputForm(request.form)
        form1 = InputForm1(request.form)
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            if request.method == 'POST': 
                        r = form.r.data
                        t = form.t.data
                        u = form.u.data
                        s = compute(r,t,u)
            else:
                        s = None
    
            return render_template("view.html", form=form, form1=form1, s=s)
    
        
    
        if form1.validate_on_submit():
            if request.method == 'POST':
                    
                        r1 = form1.r1.data
                        t1 = form1.t1.data
                        u1 = form1.u1.data
                        s1 = compute(r1,t1,u1)
            else:
                        s1 = None
    
            return render_template("view.html", form=form, form1=form1, s1=s1)
    
        return render_template("view.html",form=form, form1=form1)
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)

from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import validators, StringField, PasswordField,FloatField, validators

class InputForm(FlaskForm):
    r = FloatField(label='var_r',default=0,validators=[validators.DataRequired()])
    t = FloatField(label='var_t',default=0,validators=[validators.DataRequired()])
    u = FloatField(label='var_u',default=0,validators=[validators.DataRequired()])


class InputForm1(FlaskForm):
    r1 = FloatField(label='var_r1',default=0,validators=[validators.DataRequired()])
    t1 = FloatField(label='var_t1',default=0,validators=[validators.DataRequired()])
    u1 = FloatField(label='var_u1',default=0,validators=[validators.DataRequired()])

import math

def compute(r,t,u):
    return (math.sin(r))* t + u

<form method="post" action="">
{{ form.csrf_token }}
  {% for field in form %}
  
    <dt>{{ field.name }}
    <dd>{{ field|safe }} {{field.label }}

    
    {% if field.errors %}
      <ul class=errors>
      {% for error in field.errors %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
      {% endfor %}</ul>
    {% endif %}</dd>
  {% endfor %}

<p><input type=submit value=Compute0></form></p>
<h5> Valor: </h5>
<p>
{% if s != None %}
{{ s }}
{% endif %}
</p>

<form method="post" action="">
{{ form.csrf_token }}
  {% for field in form1 %}
  
    <dt>{{ field.name }}
    <dd>{{ field|safe }} {{field.label }}
    {% if field.errors %}
      <ul class=errors>
      {% for error in field.errors %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
      {% endfor %}</ul>
    {% endif %}</dd>
  {% endfor %}
 
<p><input type=submit value=Compute1></form></p>
<h5> Valor: </h5>
<p>
{% if s1 != None %}
{{ s1 }}
{% endif %}
</p>
```

Comment: i guess you need `{{ form1.csrf_token }}` not `{{ form.csrf_token }}` in the second form.

Comment: I tried it. Not works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand your description, you have **2 independent forms** on the **same page** that **both** send `POST` requests to the **same view function** to process.

you want to update the **placeholder** below of each form depending on which form is already submitted, here i think you need to perform an `ajax` call since (based on your code above) there's no way to keep or persist the data of the other form (database for e.g)

so to do:

- update the code of the Form `InputForm`

since the 2 forms have the same fields you need just one for this use case and then adapt and extend the logic for other forms with different set of fields

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms.fields import FloatField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired


class InputForm(FlaskForm):
    r = FloatField('r', validators=[DataRequired()])
    t = FloatField('t', validators=[DataRequired()])
    u = FloatField('u', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

- update the template

```
<!-- the first form -->
<form class="form" id="form-1" method="POST" novalidate>
  {{ form_1.csrf_token }}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          {{ form_1.r.label(class="col-form-label") }} <span class="text-danger">*</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          {{ form_1.r(class="form-control rounded-0 shadow-none", **{"placeholder":"0"}) }}
          <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          {{ form_1.t.label(class="col-form-label") }} <span class="text-danger">*</span>
        </div>
       <div class="col-sm-9">
         {{ form_1.t(class="form-control rounded-0 shadow-none", **{"placeholder":"0"}) }}
         <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          {{ form_1.u.label(class="col-form-label") }} <span class="text-danger">*</span>
        </div>
       <div class="col-sm-9">
         {{ form_1.u(class="form-control rounded-0 shadow-none", **{"placeholder":"0"}) }}
         <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row d-flex justify-content-between border bg-light p-3">
    {{ form_1.submit(class="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded-0 shadow-none") }}
    <span class="placeholder">sin(r) * t + u = 0.00</span>
  </div>
</form>

<!-- the second form -->
<form class="form" id="form-2" method="POST" novalidate>
  {{ form_2.csrf_token }}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          {{ form_2.r.label(class="col-form-label") }} <span class="text-danger">*</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          {{ form_2.r(class="form-control rounded-0 shadow-none", **{"placeholder":"0"}) }}
          <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          {{ form_2.t.label(class="col-form-label") }} <span class="text-danger">*</span>
        </div>
       <div class="col-sm-9">
         {{ form_2.t(class="form-control rounded-0 shadow-none", **{"placeholder":"0"}) }}
         <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          {{ form_2.u.label(class="col-form-label") }} <span class="text-danger">*</span>
        </div>
       <div class="col-sm-9">
         {{ form_2.u(class="form-control rounded-0 shadow-none", **{"placeholder":"0"}) }}
         <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row d-flex justify-content-between border bg-light p-3">
    {{ form_2.submit(class="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded-0 shadow-none") }}
    <span class="placeholder">sin(r) * t + u = 0.00</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

in your view function (here i just i isolated the logic in `Blueprint` `@bp`):

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, jsonify

from .forms import InputForm
from .utils import compute


bp = Blueprint(
    'home', 
    __name__, 
    static_folder='static',
    static_url_path='/home/static',
    template_folder='templates',
    # url_prefix=None,
    # subdomain=None,
    # url_defaults=None,
    # root_path=None,
    # cli_group=<object object>
)


@bp.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def index():

    form_1 = InputForm()
    form_2 = InputForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        # we handle the "POST" request of the submitted "form_1"
        if form_1.validate_on_submit():
            r = form_1.r.data
            t = form_1.t.data
            u = form_1.u.data
            s = compute(r,t,u)
            return jsonify(s=s if s else 0, errors={})
        else:
            return jsonify(s=0, errors=form_1.errors)
        
        # we handle the "POST" request of the submitted "form_2"
        if form_2.validate_on_submit():
            r = form_2.r.data
            t = form_2.t.data
            u = form_2.u.data
            s = compute(r,t,u)
            return jsonify(s=s if s else 0, errors={})
        else:
            return jsonify(errors=form_2.errors)

    return render_template("home/index.html", form_1=form_1, form_2=form_2)
```

- the `ajax` part:

i suggest you my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62641283/how-to-use-python-flask-in-javascript-file-js/62643201#62643201) on how to take advantage of `jinja2` template inheritance to insert **locally** a `js` (the same with `css`) blocks for particular page.

base on, i assume your are using `jquery` and since we want `jinja2` to render this javascript line `url: "{{ url_for('home.index') }}",` so in your `template` add this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";

  $('.form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // get the id of the form currently submitted
    let id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
      url: "{{ url_for('home.index') }}",
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $('#' + id).serialize(),  // serialize the form
      success: function(data) {

        // console.log(data);


        // sanitize the form before processing the submitted fields
        if( ! data.errors.hasOwnProperty('r')){
          $('#' + id + ' input[name=r]').removeClass('is-invalid').next(".invalid-feedback").text('');
        }
        
        if( ! data.errors.hasOwnProperty('t')){
          $('#' + id + ' input[name=t]').removeClass('is-invalid').next(".invalid-feedback").text('');
        }
        
        if( ! data.errors.hasOwnProperty('u')){
          $('#' + id + ' input[name=u]').removeClass('is-invalid').next(".invalid-feedback").text('');
        }


        // @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object
        if( ! jQuery.isEmptyObject(data.errors)) { // Errors (data.errors = {})

            console.log('Errors');
          
            if(data.errors.hasOwnProperty('r')){
              $('#' + id + ' input[name=r]').addClass('is-invalid').next(".invalid-feedback").text(data.errors['r']);
            }

            if(data.errors.hasOwnProperty('t')){
              $('#' + id + ' input[name=t]').addClass('is-invalid').next(".invalid-feedback").text(data.errors['t']);
            }

            if(data.errors.hasOwnProperty('u')){
              $('#' + id + ' input[name=u]').addClass('is-invalid').next(".invalid-feedback").text(data.errors['u']);
            }

          // update placeholder with the returned value
          $('#' + id + ' .placeholder').html('sin(r) * t + u = ' + data.s);


          } else { // Passed

          console.log('Passed');

          // get the submitted fields
          let r = $('#' + id + ' input[name=r]').val();
          let t = $('#' + id + ' input[name=t]').val();
          let u = $('#' + id + ' input[name=u]').val();

          // update placeholder with the returned value
          $('#' + id + ' .placeholder').html('sin(' + r + ') * ' + t + ' + ' + u + ' = ' + data.s);

          // reset fields
          $('#' + id + ' input[name=r]').val('');
          $('#' + id + ' input[name=t]').val('');
          $('#' + id + ' input[name=u]').val('');
        }
        
      }
    });
  });

});
```

and finally this a [image: screenshot]

hope this solves your issue.

Comment: yes, i make an assumption `jquery` is already loaded, maybe my answer on other topic could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62641283/how-to-use-python-flask-in-javascript-file-js/62643201#62643201

Comment: Error message:

jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined

"i assume your are using jquery, so in your template add this code"
I'm learning flask. 
I don't know anything about jquery yet.

Comment: @An225 i updated my answer with code reviewed, it works for sure (it just used one blueprint) to isolate the logic.

Comment: your answers are challenging for me. Now I have to learn Blueprint.

Comment: and i enjoy challenges, that's why i put much time on stackoverflow hunting good questions, reading from many sources and try developing a working apps. i would recommend you starting with the official flask tutorial and then **prettyprinted** youtube channel.